# Java:Is there some utility method to calculate

Tags: java

Now I hava a `String lam = "(8-2*7.5)+10"` ,so is there any method or class to calculate this **String expression** and *return me the result directly*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    double res = (Double) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval("(8-2*7.5)+10");
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `js` and not `JavaScript`?

Comment: I am sure because I tested it and got 3.0

Comment: Seems like that engine has several aliases. `JavaScript` works too and returns same script engine.

Comment: Yes, I checked javadocs it says shortName - The short name of the ScriptEngine implementation. returned by the getNames method of its ScriptEngineFactory

Answer (score 2):

java 1.6 provides Javascript engine within. You can use that to calculate your mathematical expression.

clases to be used are : `ScriptEngineManager` and `ScriptEngine`

Comment: Perhaps not the solution the original poster had in mind while asking, but the most pragmatical one. (If he uses a suitable version of java)

Comment: Ya that's true that java 6 and later provides the javascript engine which solves the problem very easily. If you have some better solution which fits to all versions of java then please do post. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not by default.  This would correspond to either runtime interpretation of Java code (eeek!) or parsing and interpretation machinery for a fairly trivial arithmetic sub-language embedded within the Java standard library.

If you need to parse and evaluate expressions of this sort, I would consider writing a simple recursive-descent parser and evaluating on-the-fly.  A quick Google search should suggest ways to do this in Java for languages of precisely this sort.